# Helm and GrayLog: allow_leading_wildcard_searches

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to k8s using helm and I actually got a little problem.

They are using a git repository with a values.yaml to configure the graylog. How am I supposed to set "allow_leading_wildcard_searches = true" in the yaml file?

I already checked the Helm Chart Repository but I couldn't help myself..

Answer (score 1):

In https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/graylog/values.yaml you can see that you can add additional graylog config.

```
...
 config: |
    elasticsearch_connect_timeout = 10s
    elasticsearch_socket_timeout = 60s
    elasticsearch_idle_timeout = -1s
...
```

The answer would be to set the following in the values.yaml:

```
...
  config: |
    allow_leading_wildcard_searches = true
...
```